# Are Java web applications prepared differently than java console based application using Apache Axis2?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis

I am working on consuming web services from some "System". I have created my web service client using Apache Axis2.

Now I am stuck with one situation

1) if i am testing this client with java console based application, it's working fine

> LogonRequestDocument logonRequestDoc =
>   LogonRequestDocument)getTestObject(LogonRequestDocument.class);

Here, `LogonRequestDocument` is an `Interface,`

`getTestObject()` method is implemented as follows:

```
public org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject getTestObject(java.lang.Class type) throws java.lang.Exception {
    java.lang.reflect.Method creatorMethod = null;
    if (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        Class[] declaredClasses = type.getDeclaredClasses();
        for (int i = 0; i < declaredClasses.length; i++) {
            Class declaredClass = declaredClasses[i];
            if (declaredClass.getName().endsWith("$Factory")) {
                creatorMethod = declaredClass.getMethod("newInstance", null);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    if (creatorMethod != null) {
        return (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject) creatorMethod.invoke(null, null);
    } else {
        throw new java.lang.Exception("Creator not found!");
    }
}
```

Here, `creatorMethod.invoke(null,null)` method works fine with Java console application, but the same code throws exception when employed in web application.

I would like to know if is there any difference between both the console and web app in Java using Axis2.

Using console application, this `getTestObj()` works fine, and doesn't give any exception, but when the same code is used in web application, `ExceptionInInitializerError`- if the initialization provoked by this method fails, this exception occurs.

I need help with correct implementation of preparing and using web service.

Comment: You should post the complete stack trace of the exception

Comment: Well, Thank you so much Carlos, the problem is solved, it wasn't a major one, actually this was some reflection code which was wrapping the actual exception. My console based java application was working fine. Web based application was getting stuck at the same line of code and throwing exception from that point, where this reflection code was getting called, and i was missing some binary files which were there in the src folder and were not available in the tomcat compiled classes. and i was thinking like my web service client had some problem. anyways, Thank you so much for your response :)